# do we need separate icons for iPad and iPhone?

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, icons

I am thinking of designing a a website which sort of looks like an app.So im in the process of designing the icons and creating the css for it. I was wondering if I have to do separate icons for iPhone and iPad bcos iPad will surely need bigger icons.Sorry if I posted the question in the wrong section.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[iOS Human Interface Guidelines - Web Clip Icons](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW11):

> For iPhone and iPod touch, create
>   icons that measure:
>
> - 57 x 57 pixels
> - 114 x 114 pixels (high resolution)
>
> For iPad, create an icon that measures:
>
> - 72 x 72 pixels

[Safari Web Content Guide - Specifying a Webpage Icon for Web Clip](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW4):

> To specify multiple icons for
>   different device resolutions—for
>   example, support both iPhone and iPad
>   devices—add a sizes attribute to each
>   link element as follows:
>
> ```
> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png" />
> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="touch-icon-ipad.png" />
> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="touch-icon-iphone4.png" />
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Since the screen resolution is different for both devices, maybe you'd want to route them to completely different pages based on the user-agent string.

That way, you can design the optimal UI for both devices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be best idea to use separate style sheet
you can use following code -

because difference in DPI you have to use hi DPI for ipad and iphone's icons

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following link.
It contains an iPad like simulator in browser. It has all the images as like the iPad.
Since it is a web content, I hope that you will get some resources from here.

http://alexw.me/ipad2/

Thanks.